# JqGrid inlinenav issue with add button

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I use the inlinenav option for a jqgrid and I have an issue with the save button when I want to add a new row. I have this error message : **TypeError: e.addParams.addRowParams is undefined**

Here are my grid parameters :

```
$.ajax({
url: 'control_grid.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
     jQuery("#table").jqGrid({
        data: data,
        datatype: "local",
        rowNum: 500,
        id: "DOMAIN_ID",
        colNames:['Id','Description'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'DOMAIN_ID',index:'DOMAIN_ID',hidden:true, width:60, key:true, editable:false},
            {name:'DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION',index:'DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION', editable:true, edittype:'text'},                       
        ],
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        pager: "#pager",
        viewrecords: true,
        editurl :'crud_domain.php',
        caption: "Domain"
    });
    jQuery("#table").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
    jQuery("#table").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager");
}
});
```

I use a CRUD php page in the editurl to update my database with the grid.

I hope you will be able to help me.